# Need to find a difference of data from the same table in hive

Tags: sql, hive

I have a history table with loaded timestamp column. I need to fetch the subtracted data using the timestamp column.
Logic:To get the email address by subtracting data from (loaded_timestamp -1)and current_timestamp.Only the subtracted data should be the output.

Select query :

```
select t1.email_addr
from (select *
      from table t1
      where loaded_timestamp = current_timestamp
     ) left outer join
     (select *
      from table t2
      where loaded_timestamp = date_sub(current_timestamp,1)
    )
where t1.email!=t2.email;
```

Table has following columns

```
Email address, First name , last name, loaded_timestamp. 
xxx@gmail.com,xxx,aaa,2020-03-08.   
yyy@gmail.com,yyy,bbb,2020-03-08. 
zzz@gmail.com,zzz,ccc,2020-03-08. 
xxx@gmail.com,xxx,aaa,2020-03-09. 
yyy@gmail.com,yyy,bbb,2020-03-09.
```

Desired Result

```
zzz@gmail.com
```

So if subtract the two dates from the same table i.e (2020-03-09 - 2020-03-08 ). I should get only the record which is not matching . Matching records should be discarded and unmatched record should be the output.

Comment: I have supplied all the details . Dataset looks like above example mentioned , which will have repetitive data’s with loaded_ timestamp column . My expectation is to get the email which is not present in current date. Note : t1 n t2 belongs to same table.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can figure out is that you want emails that appear only once.  If that is the case, use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by email) as cnt
      from t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

If you want emails in the data but not loaded on the current date, then:

```
select t.email
from t
group by t.email
having max(timestamp) <> current_date;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your reply.  I need to get the email which is not present today . If a record matches the dataset  from yesterday to today’s date , It should be discarded and only the unmatched record of yesterday’s should be my output.

Comment: @SaranyaRavikumar . . . That is what the second query does.